# Exception parsing document when deploying spring boot jar project on a aws

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, thymeleaf

When launching the application from STS, the application works fine and I can access everything. 
But once I create a jar file using mvn clean install, and then deploying this on an aws ec2 I get the following error :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this 
as a fallback.

Thu Sep 14 08:46:01 UTC 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception parsing document
```

Any reason why it would show this ?
Thank you

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#spring-boot-and-error-handling